# Which types should my Entity Framework repository and service layer methods return: List, IEnumerable, IQueryable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, architecture

I have a concrete repository implementation that returns a IQueryable of the entity:

```
public class Repository
{
    private AppDbContext context;

    public Repository()
    {
        context = new AppDbContext();
    }


    public IQueryable<Post> GetPosts()
    {
        return context.Posts;
    }
}
```

My service layer can then perform LINQ as needed for other methods (where, paging, etc)

Right now my service layer is setup to return IEnumerable:

```
public IEnumerable<Post> GetPageOfPosts(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{ 
    Repository postRepo = new Repository();

    var posts = (from p in postRepo.GetPosts()  //this is IQueryable
                orderby p.PostDate descending
                select p)
                .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize);

    return posts;
}
```

This means in my codebehind I have to do a ToList() if I want to bind to a repeater or other control.

Is this the best way to handle the return types or do I need to be converting to list before I return from my service layer methods?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both approaches are possible and it is only matter of choice.

Once you use `IQueryable` you have simple repository which will work in the most cases but it is worse testable because queries defined on `IQueryable` are linq-to-entities. If you mock repository they are linq-to-objects in unit tests = you don't test your real implementation. You need integration tests to test your query logic.

Once you use `IEnumerable` you will have very complex public interfaces of your repositories - you will need special repository type for every entity which needs special query exposed on the repository. This kind of repositories was more common with stored procedures - each method on the repository was mapped to single stored procedure. This type of repository provides better separation of concerns and less leaky abstraction but in the same time it removes a lot of ORM and Linq flexibility.

For the last you can have combined approach where you have methods returning IEnumerable for most common scenarios (queries used more often) and one method exposing `IQueryable` for rare or complex dynamically build queries.

Edit:

As noted in comments using `IQueryable` has some side effects. When you expose `IQueryable` you must keep your context alive until you execute the query - `IQueryable` uses deferred execution in the same way as `IEnumerable` so unless you call `ToList`, `First` or other functions executing your query you still need your context alive.

The simplest way to achieve that is using disposable pattern in the repository - create context in its constructor and dispose it when repository disposes. Then you can use `using` blocks and execute queries inside them. This approach is for very simple scenarios where you are happy with single context per repository. More complex (and common) scenarios require context to be shared among multiple repositories. In such case you can use something like context provider / factory (disposable) and inject the factory to repository constructor (or allow provider to create repositories). This leads to DAL layer factory and custom unit of work.

Comment: Still learning and system is not too complex, so trying to avoid any complex architecture, but still separate concerns.  So, better to let the service layer consumer (UI/Codebehind) do the ToList as needed?

Comment: I like it more but it includes some complexities with testing (if you use automated tests) and it requires controlling lifetime of context carefully (as @jwJung pointed) because when you call `ToList` the context must be still alive.

Comment: So to avoid potential lifetime of context I should do the ToList in service layer so that I know the data has been extracted from the db by the time it reaches the presentation layer?  Beyond the using (context), what more should I do?  Move the dbcontext into the service layer?  There has to be some middle ground between full generic implementation with interfaces and just putting all the code procedurally in the codebehind?!

Comment: The way this is commonly done is either through some context factory or custom unit of work. In such case you do not call `using(context)` but you have some central place where you create and dispose context / uow - for example you can have context factory which check if the context is in `HttpContext.Current.Items` if yes it returns this instance and if not it creates a new one, stores it in the items and returns it. You also need custom `IHttpModule` to handle context disposal on request end.

Answer (score 3):

The other word for your question seems to need to determine when the `AppDbContext` is disposed or where it is.

If you don't dispose it, meaning it's disposed when a application exits, it is no problem to return IEnumerable/IQueryable, no having actual data. However, you would need to return the type as IList, having actual data, before the `AppDbContext` is disposed.

**UPDATE:**
I think you would need to catch the following code meaning though you already know.

```
//outside of this code is refered to your code.

//Returning IEnumerable could be used outside this scope if AppDbContext is ensured no disposing
public IEnumerable<Post> GetIEnumerableWithoutActualData()
{
    return context.Posts;
}

//Even if AppDbContext is disposed, IEnumerable could be used.
public IEnumerable<Post> GetIEnumerableWithActualData()
{
    return context.Posts.ToList();
}
```

Comment: @jwJung - as long as I use the context in a "using" statement, I should not have to explicitly dispose of it, correct?

Comment: However, if you return the type as IQueryable, no having actual data, I think that the type throws `System.ObjectDisposedException` after the `AppDbContext` is disposed. So you would need to archive the type as IList before the disposing.

Comment: +1 very good point. Once you return `IQueryable` you must control lifetime of the context outside of the repository.

Comment: Once I query against and convert to IEnumerable, I should be safe though, correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to consider the lifetime of the context as @Ladislav Mrnka is also mentioned. Please refer to my updated answer

Comment: The whole reason for using IQueryable in the repo was so I could then do filtering and paging from the service layer and not have to create the extra methods in repo for every where/paging need.  Maybe the best of both worlds will be to do the IQueryable from repo, but then make sure I to ToList() from my service layer, that way I should not run into DbContext lifetime issues. How is everyone else handling issues like this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the `IQueryable<T>` but it would cause the lifetime issue, throwing the `System.ObjectDisposedException`. If my understanding is true, you could use `IEnumerable<T>.AsQueryable<T>()' as a extension method to convert the `IEnumerable<T>` to the `Queryable<T>`. My code above(UPDATE) is a example case. The important thing is , at the my code, to determind whether the returning object is the `List` or the `IEnumberable<T>`.

Comment: if any of your code doesn't has the DbContext disposing code, you can return the IEnumerable<T>/IQueryable<T>. On the contrary, if the DbContext disposes anywhere, you should return the type like the `List<T>`, having data before the disposing.

Comment: In the other word, if you want the client to decide to use or manipulate data, you shouldn't close/dispose the DbContext, and could return the IEnumerable<T>/IQueryable<T> object.  I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Your returns types should always be as high up on the inheritance hierarchy as possible (*or maybe I should write that as **low**, if the base is towards the bottom*). If all your methods require `IQueryable<T>`, then all the return values should surrender that type.

That said, `IEnumerable<T>` has a method ([`AsQueryable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx)) you can call to achieve (what I believe to be) the desired result.

Comment: I was only planning to use the IQueryable from the repository so I could then do filtering/sorting/paging from the service layer as needed without having to duplicate code with extra pass through methods.