# Entity Framework 4 Unit of Work / Repository WITHOUT .Query() Lambda

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

We've seen some very useful methods of implementing EF4 Repository and Unit of Work pattern ([Reference 1](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/06/21/revisiting-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework.aspx), [Reference 2](https://github.com/danemorgridge/efrepo))

All the examples I see use methods requiring the use of LINQ Expression Syntax, e.g.:

```
IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter) 

var employees = employeeRepository.Query(emp => emp.Username == userName);
```

But I want to use LINQ Query Expression syntax, e.g.:

```
from emp in context.Employees select emp where emp.Username == userName;
```

Is there a way to enjoy the benefits of a repository and UoW whilst being able to use LINQ Query Expression syntax in my repository methods?

Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but you must expose `IQueryable<T>`:

```
IQueryable<T> Query();
```

After that you can use code like:

```
var query = from emp in EmployeeRepository.Query() 
            where emp.Username == userName
            select emp;
```

The [difference between approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416506/which-types-should-my-entity-framework-repository-and-service-layer-methods-retur/6416637#6416637) was discussed yesterday. Also whole concept of repository and unit of work was discussed many times - including [why to use them and what problems you can expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762846/is-unitofwork-and-genericrepository-pattern-redundant-in-ef-4-1-code-first/5763551#5763551).

Comment: +1 That's the way I do it too. It still enables lambda expressions such as employeeRepository.Query().Where(emp => emp.UserName == userName);

Comment: That looks good. I know the repository discussion has been done to death. Funny 2 discussions on this topic hit around the same time :) I think the fact there are so many discussions around these topics serves to highlight some pretty serious weaknesses in EF4.