# Error multiple objects with the same key DbContext

Tags: c#, dbcontext, updating

I am getting an Error

> "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key."

I used this method in two places. In first place - work correctly, but in second I have error.

How decided this problem?

My method:

```
public static void UpdateMehod(ModelEntities context, ProcessedFilest processedFiles)
{
    context.Set<ProcessedFiles>().Attach(processedFiles);
    context.Entry(processedFiles).Property(p => p.ID).IsModified = true;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I create new method:

public static void UpdateProtocol(ModelEntities context, ProcessedFilesXml processedFilesXml)
        {
            var entry = context.Entry(processedFilesXml);

```
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            var set = context.Set<ProcessedFilesXml>();
            ProcessedFilesXml attachedEntity = set.Find(processedFilesXml.ProcessedFileXmlID); 

            if (attachedEntity != null)
            {
                var attachedEntry = context.Entry(attachedEntity);
                attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(processedFilesXml);
            }
            else
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified; 
            }
        }

        //context.Set<ProcessedFilesXml>().Attach(processedFilesXml);
        //context.Entry(processedFilesXml).Property(p => p.Protocol).IsModified = true;
        //context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But I don't know ho create savechanges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the entity from the context you cannot attach an entity with the same key agai.See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585664/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033638/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object)

```
public override void Update(T entity) where T : IEntity {
    if (entity == null) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add a null entity.");
    }

    var entry = _context.Entry<T>(entity);

    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached) {
        var set = _context.Set<T>();
        T attachedEntity = set.Find(entity.Id);  // You need to have access to key

        if (attachedEntity != null) {
            var attachedEntry = _context.Entry(attachedEntity);
            attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        } else {
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified; // This should attach entity
        }
    }
enter code here
```

}