# Different database repository implementations behind single interface

Tags: c#, architecture, repository-pattern, data-access-layer

I am working on an application for which I need to write a data access layer. My first thought was to create a bunch of repositories for each entity that I need but I am now facing the a challenge with separating the different actions of a repository. I would like to hear your thoughts on this.

First, I would like to support two types of communication to the database - direct sql queries (for example, insert into, update, etc) and bulk inserts like loading data from a file (or other source). However, both of these implementation do different things:

- The simple repository fires a query to SQL server
- The bulk repository first adds a record to a file or in memory. Once it is done processing all records, it synchronizes with the database.

My first attempt at the class structure for this is:

```
  public class Product{

  }

  public interface IProductRepository {
    Product GetProduct(int id);
    void CreateProduct(Product p);
  }

  public class SqlProductRepository : IProductRepository
  {
    public Product GetProduct(int id)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CreateProduct(Product p)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }   
  }

  public class BulkLoadRepository : IProductRepository
  {
    public Product GetProduct(int id)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CreateProduct(Product p)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }    
  }
```

However, this structure is missing a synchronization function at the end for the bulk repository. If I do end up adding a Sync() function, I will need to leave it empty for the "simple" repository.

Any thoughts on how to support both functionalities but still hide them behind one interface?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why are you creating an interface for each object type. A repository would usually just have Get, Create, Update, Delete methods for example, maybe a generic Get...  where the IRepository is also generic.

You could have a second interface inheriting `IRepository` which has the `Sync` method and only the Bulk repository implements that one. In this case you can still access both repositories`methods defined by`IProductRepository`

Or have a base class for Bulk repositories which implements/defines sync.

Comment: I would like to have a separate interface for each object type to control the functionalities being supported. I do like your idea over the second interface - I think this is what I am going with. This will also allow me to check if the repository implements ICommitChanges - sync the changes to the db.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would leave it empty for the simple repository.  Sync == Commit in most of my repositories.  Although more precisely this is the UnitOfWork pattern, not the repository pattern.

Exposing a separate commit method is very common for transactional systems.

[Repository and Unit of Work patterns - How to save changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263331/repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-how-to-save-changes)

Comment: In other cases I have a commit indeed (with the UnitOfWork). However, in this case I don't want to have a commit because what I am working on is not a typical transactional system (i don't want to persist changes or use a transaction). However, it is something that I will consider indeed.